# Loader is stuck and doesn't navigate to next page - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented a loader from flutter_spinkit package, the loader appears when users navigate to another page through the navigation drawer, the problem is when user clicks the button that navigate to another page the loader appears and stuck without closing or navigating, here is the code :

```
onTap: () async {
                //Close the navigation Drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);

                //Show dialog that contains the loader
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  barrierDismissible: false,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return WillPopScope(
                      onWillPop: () async {
                        return false;
                      },
                      child: SpinKitCircle(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );

                //Close the Loader Dialog after 3 seconds (it doesn't close)
                await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                });
                
                //Navigate to the next page 
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const MyChallenges(),
                  ),
                );
              },
```

Console is showing this :

```
E/flutter ( 6263): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 6263): #0      StatefulElement.state
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4926
E/flutter ( 6263): #1      Navigator.of
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2542
E/flutter ( 6263): #2      Navigator.pop
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2432
E/flutter ( 6263): #3      _NavigationDrawerState.buildMenuItems.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:athaddakapp/screens/navigation_drawer.dart:123
E/flutter ( 6263): #4      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:423:39)
E/flutter ( 6263): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
E/flutter ( 6263): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 6263): #7      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter ( 6263): #8      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter ( 6263): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
E/flutter ( 6263): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 6263): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1260:23)
E/flutter ( 6263): #12     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter ( 6263): #13     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter ( 6263): #14     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter ( 6263): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

the loader keeps loads and doesn't navigate, ill appreciate any idea. Thank you

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console? if not try to put this code in the try-catch block and print the error in the catch block.

Comment: i have added the console result

Comment: check the logs you are getting a null value somewhere. show more logs to find out

Comment: when i removed the first line it worked, so i believe the context is the navigation drawer but it is closed

Comment: okay fine. happy coding :)

Comment: but actually i still need the first line to close the drawer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use global key in main for context in showDialog and Navigator.pop which is used to close the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Use main widget `context` to navigate.

Simply change `showDialog` context name

`builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {` or `builder: (_) {`

Comment: Still stuck, please check the console error am getting i have added to question, thank you

Comment: how to use the main context if you may ?

Comment: Pass your main widget/page `context` to your class / drawer and use this context to navigate.